# Is there a way to modify or redefine a type of org-link locally?

Tags: org-mode, customize

I am searching for the best strategy to define custom behaviour for `file:` org-links locally to a buffer. Is there a way to modify or redefine this type of org-link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the more elegant approach consist on setting locally `org-link-abbrev-alist` in some buffers, following its name, so that `file:` links get overloaded.

```
(setq-local org-link-abbrev-alist
        '(("file" . "%(custom logic)")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tweak `org-open-at-point` of `org.el`. It contains the following lines:

```
((string= type "file")
 (if (string-match "::\\([0-9]+\\)\\'" path)
     (setq line (string-to-number (match-string 1 path))
           path (substring path 0 (match-beginning 0)))
   (if (string-match "::\\(.+\\)\\'" path)
       (setq search (match-string 1 path)
             path (substring path 0 (match-beginning 0)))))
 (when (string-match "[*?{]" (file-name-nondirectory path))
   (dired path)
   (org-open-file path arg line search)
   )
 )
```

So if you'd manage to enclose the behavior you want in a variable, then you can adjust its value for a given buffer (for example it can contain a regexp, a binary name, or just some elisp code), and you are done.

What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using gitit to write a wiki; file links to pages behave differently in the org buffer and the resulting html wiki page, exported by pandoc, so I have to adapt org behaviour to gitit

Comment: @csantosb: I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Under gitit links to wiki pages must appear as `[[file:/category1/category2/mypage][my-page]]`, regardless of the page they appear on, and  they are relative to the top level. Problem is, this is meaningless to org, unless I redefine `file:` links locally